# Quickest way of Importing 500GB Text File taking only the sections wanted

Tags: python, text, replace

I have about 500GB of text file seperated in months. In these text files the first 43 lines are just connection information (not needed). the next 75 lines are descriptors for an observation. This is followed by 4 lines (not needed) then the next observation which is 75 lines.

The thing is all I want are these 75 lines (descriptors are in the same place for every observation) which are characterized like this:

```
ID: 5523
Date: 20052012
Mixed: <Null>
.
.
```

And I want to change it to csv format `5523;20052012;;..` for each observation. So that I end up with much smaller text files. Since the descriptors are the same I'll know the first position for example is ID.

Once I finish with the text file I'll be opening the next one and appending it (or would creating a new file be quicker?).

What I've done is quite inefficient I've been opening the file. Loading it. Deleting these observations going line by line. If it's taking a fair bit with a test sample it clearly isn't the best method.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Are any portions of your files fixed length?

Comment: Yes, hence the name: [CSV, Comma-Separated Values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Comment: Can you post your sample code, the one that is taking some time with your sample of the final data set.

Comment: No they are not, but every observation is on a seperate line. so ID has a line and then the next line is Date, so on and so forth. (Sorry I just realized the question didn't format it properly)

Comment: @ColeJohnson, @voithos: Not really. Read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) (#3) and the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). Notice a `delimiter` keyword argument.

Comment: @Blender: True. I suppose I just wanted to clarify the acronym - not that it matters much.

Comment: The four lines you don't need, are they equal between the 75 line blocks for the observations? E.G. four blank lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said that you have "about 500GB of text files." If I understand correctly, you don't have a fixed length for each observation (note, I'm not talking about the number of *lines*, I mean the total length, in bytes, of all of the lines for an observation). This means that you *will* have to go through the entire file, because you can't know exactly where the newlines are going to be.

Now, depending on how large each individual text file is, you may need to look for a different answer. But if each file is sufficiently small (less than 1 GB?), you might be able to use the [`linecache`](http://docs.python.org/library/linecache.html) module, which handles the seeking-by-line for you.

You'd use it perhaps like this:

```
import linecache

filename = 'observations1.txt'

# Start at 44th line
curline = 44
lines = []

# Keep looping until no return string is found
# getline() never throws errors, but returns an empty string ''
# if the line wasn't found (if the line was actually empty, it would have
# returned the newline character '\n')
while linecache.getline(filename, curline):
    for i in xrange(75):
        lines.append(linecache.getline(filename, curline).rstrip())
        curline += 1

    # Perform work with the set of observation lines
    add_to_observation_log(lines)

    # Skip the unnecessary section and reset the lines list
    curline += 4
    lines = []
```

I tried a test of this, and it chewed through a 23MB file in five seconds.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to this module. The data is about 1GB is a little larger on occasion but I think this should work for its size. The reason I tried to stay away from using lists is that I hae a problem writing them. Working from your code I've quickly adapted it for my uses:

Comment: while linecache.getline(filename, curline):    
for i in range(75):
        data_manipulated = linecache.getline(filename, curline).rstrip()
        datamanipulated2=data_manipulated.split(":")
        datamanipulated2.pop(0)

        lines.append(datamanipulated2) 
        curline += 1
  /* with open ('outputfile',"a") as f:
           ## f.write(lines) /* This gives you an error that 'list' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: So I decided to be clever.... 
And tried the following:
f= print (', '.join(map(str, lines)))
Then you get the following error TypeError: must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper
I feel like the awnser is ery simple but I'm missing it, any suggestions?
Thanks again for the linecache module.

Comment: @FancyDolphin: So it appears that you're uninterested in the keys (`ID:`, `Date:`, etc) and only want to extract the data. That's fine. As for writing it out, just iterate over the list and write it out. [Here's an example](http://pastebin.com/UhXh7iTB). Also, in the future, when you need to post code in a comment, put it up on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or a similar tool and just post a link. It's easier to read.

Comment: A couple comments on the code. I had thought of avoiding pop however that method leads to the following error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) which is why I opted for the longer solution. I might not understand how to implement it. 
I've provided the following code I'm using however, there is a problem I had just noticed. For some reason the data pull is for half my obseration and just stops for some reason. I couldn't figure it out why that could be the case. The following is the link to the code: http://pastebin.com/iWPybGut. Any suggestions on making it faster

Comment: @FancyDolphin: The error means that your data has multiple colons in it at some point, and is getting split into more than two values. If that's the case, then the `pop()` should work, but instead of `append()`ing the resulting list, try appending the join of that result, i.e. `lines.append(':'.join(datamanipulated2))`

Comment: I like that lines.append, works well. I'm stumped though by the fact that the loop is stopping before returning all the strings in the text. I tried to force it to keep going until it reached the number of lines in the text, but that didn't work. Any suggestions why this could be the case?

Comment: @FancyDolphin: Are you sure that you're not just overlooking the fact that you're condensing the 75 lines of data into a single CSV line?

Comment: Not at all. I check the first condensed observation and it's done correctly. Then I check for the last observation and it's not there. The last condensed line in my observation_log is the middle observation of my file.

Comment: @FancyDolphin: I just saw that in your code you were looping: `for i in range(72)` - is that intentional? Didn't you say it was **75**?

Comment: I said that. But having run the loop I realized I was off by 3. So it was a quick adjustment.

Comment: @FancyDolphin: I see. Well, at this point, I can't say much else without seeing the input file. I suppose, just make sure that there aren't any discrepancies (like the 4 lines of unneeded info being more than 4 lines sometimes), as that will throw off the numbering.

Answer (score 2):

> opening the file. Loading it. Deleting these observations going line by line.

What do you mean by "loading it"? If you mean reading the entire thing into a string, then yes this is going to suck. The natural way to handle the file is to take advantage of the fact that the file object is an iterator over the lines of the file:

```
for line in file:
    if should_use(line): do_something_with(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider writing the information you want to keep into a database. In python you can use sqlite3 which is built in. It is easy to understand fom the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html).

You say that you now exactly the lines in each file, that you want to keep. So you can try something like this.

```
    import csv
    reader = csv.reader(open("afile.csv","rb"),delimiter="\t",quotechar='"')
    info_to_keep = []
    obs = []
    for row in reader:
       i+=1
       if i<43:
           continue
       elif i-43 <79*(len(info_to_keep)+1)-4:
           obs.append(row)
       elif i-43 <79*(len(info_to_keep)+1):
           continue
       else:
           info_to_keep.append(obs)
           obs = [row]
```

That way you can have a list named info_to_keep with each entry containing a list with 75 entries, each containg a list with the fields from the csv-file